# How to Hide box or button when mouse is not on them

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am trying to implement an effect that when I put the mouse over the box, the button component will show and make the box a bit bigger, and when the mouse is out the button won't show and the box size get a big smaller.

````
const Container = styled.div`
    flex:1;
    margin: 15px;
    min-width:  350px;
    max-width: 350px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: none;
    z-index: 3;
    justify-content: center;
    
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
    &:hover{
        background-color: #a5e293;
    }
`;
const Button = styled.button`
font-size: 1em;
margin: 1em;
padding: 0.25em 1em;
border: 2px solid palevioletred;
border-radius: 3px;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
`;

const Product = ({item}:any) => {
    return (
        <Container>      
            <img src={item.imagem} className='imag'/>
            <Box justifyContent='center' display='flex'>
            <Typography>
                {item.nome}
                
            </Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box justifyContent='center' display='flex'>
            <Typography>
                {item.preco}
            </Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box justifyContent='center' display='flex'>
            <Button>Comprar</Button>
                </Box>
        </Container>
    )
}```

This is my code without the changes I tried, because it was pretty messy
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional rendering or with styles. Below are examples, the first with conditional rendering, the second with styles.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Container = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  margin: 15px;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: none;
  z-index: 3;
  justify-content: center;

  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #a5e293;
  }
`
const Button = styled.button`
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
`

const Product = ({ item }) => {
  const [isButtonVisible, setButtonVisible] = useState(false)

  const handleButtonToggle = () => {
    setButtonVisible(!isButtonVisible)
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <img src={item.imagem} className="imag" />
      <Box justifyContent="center" display="flex">
        <Typography>{item.nome}</Typography>
      </Box>
      <Box justifyContent="center" display="flex">
        <Typography>{item.preco}</Typography>
      </Box>
      <Box
        onMouseEnter={handleButtonToggle}
        onMouseLeave={handleButtonToggle}
        justifyContent="center"
        display="flex"
      >
        Other components
        {isButtonVisible && <Button>Comprar</Button>}
      </Box>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

And with help styles.

```
const Button = styled.button`
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
  justify-content: center;
  /* initial display: none */
  display: none;
`

const StyledBox = styled(Box)`
  :hover ${Button} {
    display: flex;
  }
`
```